# Pentaho Schema Workbench dimension attributes

Tags: schema, pentaho, dimension, workbench

I use PSW 3.5.11. I have a classic dimension for people (sex, ethnicity, religion, study level, etc.) and people code.

**How can I create this dimension to use each attribute alone and not as a level?**

I know how create a dimension with hierarchy, like

`geography: Country -> Province - > Region -> City`

but Geography dimension not has same structure of People dimension.
How analyze my data by sex in a report, by ethnicity in another report? How can I create the People dimension?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the same table multiple times. 
Define one dimension gender, pointing to the table and a single level gender given by column gender; set another dimension ethnicity, pointing to the same table and a single level ethnicity given by column ethnicity. Etc.

If you prefer, you can instead set multiple hierarchies, one for each attribute, all within a single dimension People, but in practice there isn’t much difference (the MDX changes just a bit).

Comment: Thanks for you answer nsousa,
This is my solution, but I don't like...
When I open Report Analyser, I have too much groups of "mini-dimensions". I would like to see only one dimension with all attributes and hierarchy levels, if it's possible. I see that with release 4 there is "Attribute" concept (If I understand we can add attributes only with text editor...).

Comment: I can use also release 8

Comment: You can set Analyzer groups in properties. Don’t remember the syntax, you should check the doco.

Comment: I have already tried, but with "properties" when I drag the object, automatically I have the parent (for example, I drag sex and I have Customer_id).
I find, in the documentation, the concept of "parentColumn". If I have always the same parent (customer_id column), perhaps I can analyse my data how I want

Comment: You will need to set Analyzer groups, not properties. It’s not available though schema workbench, you need to edit it directly in thr xml.

Comment: Thank you nsousa, I think your last answer is correct.
I find this in the doc https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0N0/020/070/020/010
I'm testing.